# How to run python function using html form as input?

Tags: javascript, python, html

I have a html form asking for album selection from a menu and client's email address from an input.

```html
<form>
    <h3>Please select an album:</h3>
    <select>
      <option>2016_May_Birthday_Party</option>
      <option>2016_April_Birthday_Party</option>
      <option>test_3</option>
    </select>
    <p></p>
    <h3>Please enter your email: <input type="text" name="emailadd"></h3>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

I would like to take the user's selection and email address as argument to run `SendMail(recipient, album)` function in `sendmail.py` on the server to send an email to the client. New to web programming, thanks for help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*There is no easy and short answer to this question.*

You need some simple server running to grab data that you want to send through email and then run sending mail part.

If you are capable of learning from Python documentation, [this](https://pythonhosted.org/flask-mail/) is one of many frameworks that can be used to achieve that.

Else you might consider checking [this awesome Python web development tutorial](https://www.fullstackpython.com/web-development.html) which will help you understand how to create web applications using this great language which is Python!

Comment: Would it be easier to translate my sendmail python script into a js one to get rid of installing frameworks?

Comment: You cannot send emails by JavaScript, because JavaScript is running user side. The only way is to host web application that will send emails.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify **action** in **form** tag and create a view on the specified action's url where you can call that function. To create view you need to use anyone of the frameworks like flask, bottle, django etc.